# Why does this Supervisor not start the Genserver?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

When the Supervisor code below is invoked I expect the GenServer to start.
The GenServer does not start and I want to know why and how to fix it.

```
defmodule App.Service do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(state) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state)
  end

  def init(state) do
     {:ok, state}
  end

  def get_state(pid) do
     GenServer.call(pid, :get_state)
  end

  def set_state(pid,state) do
     GenServer.call(pid, {:set_state, state})
  end


  def handle_call(:get_state, _from, state) do
     {:reply, state, state}
  end


  def handle_call({:set_state, new_state}, _from, state)do
    {:reply,state,[new_state | state]}
  end
   
end

defmodule App.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
  end

  def init(_) do
     children = [
      App.Service
     ]
  Supervisor.init(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end



x = App.Supervisor.start()
IO.inspect x

pid = Process.whereis(App.Service)

# The following is nil. I expect a PID

IO.inspect pid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register a GenServer under a name, you should pass the `name` explicitly to `start_link/3` as explained [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration).

```elixir
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state, name: __MODULE__)
```

In your case, the genserver was started but as an anonymous process.

Comment: I'm learning Elixir. What I thought I wanted to do was to run a GenServer under a Supervisor and do so in a way that I could explicitly kill the GenServer and then verify that is automatically restarted using Process.whereis(App.Service) .  I did not know I needed to "Register the GenServer under a name" to do that. I am unclear where this relationship is made clear in the docs. Thank you

Comment: The doc can be found on the link above, and registration is mentioned in the doc for [Process.whereis/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#whereis/1). Regarding learning resources, I'd strongly recommend the getting started guide, more specifically the section which explains [processes](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/processes.html) and has a nice [intro to OTP and supervision trees](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/introduction-to-mix.html).

Comment: Any processes (GenServer included) can be referred (subsequently called) using either PID or registered name. In your case, since no name is being registered, you can still ask your Supervisor what is the PID, since it was the one who started the process. Note though that [Supervisor.which_children](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#which_children/1) will return all the processes started by the supervisor. Since you only spawned one instance of that GenServer, that method will return the only PID reference you needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your GenServer starts and it gets a randomly generated PID. You can indeed register a name during the start:

```
{:ok, _} = GenServer.start_link(MyApp, [:hello], name: :your_genserver_name)
```

And then get the PID:

```
pid = Process.whereis(:your_genserver_name)
```

Or you can try to find it with Observer (Erlang VM inspection tool) in the Applications tab:

```
:observer.start()
```